# Where can I learn about #ifdef?

Tags: haskell, ghc, c-preprocessor

I see this used often to make modules compatible with GHC and Hugs, but google is not helping me learn more about it.

What can I put inside the conditional? Can I make parts of a module conditional on what version of 'base' is in use?

**EDIT 3/2017**: This is a great resource: https://guide.aelve.com/haskell/cpp-vww0qd72

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The GHC documentation has a [section relating to the C pre-processor](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#options-affecting-the-c-pre-processor) that documents some of the predefined
pre-processor macros.

The Cabal documentation has a [section relating to conditional compilation](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#conditional-compilation) that gives an example relating to `base`.  If you are writing a portable package, you should be using Cabal, anyway.

Answer (score 25):

In addition to the very useful flags defined by GHC (OS, architecture, etc), when using cabal other flags and macros are defined.

**Check Package Versions**

Here's a use from [crypto-api](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/crypto-api/0.6.1/doc/html/src/Crypto-Modes.html) that checks the version of the `tagged` package being used:

```
#if MIN_VERSION_tagged(0,2,0)
import Data.Proxy
#endif
```

**Custom CPP Defines Based on Cabal Flags**

You can define CPP symbols dependent on cabal flags.  Here's an (unnecessarily complex) example from [pureMD5](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pureMD5/2.1.0.3/pureMD5.cabal) (from the .cabal file):

```
 if arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)
   cpp-options: -DFastWordExtract
```

Inside the `.hs` module you can then use `#ifdef`, for example:

```
#ifdef FastWordExtract
getNthWord n b = inlinePerformIO (unsafeUseAsCString b (flip peekElemOff n . castPtr))
#else
... other code ...
#endif
```

For more information you can see the Cabal users guide.  [This page](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#conditional-compilation) has the "conditional compilation" information you're probably looking for.

Answer (score 8):

`#ifdef` and friends are used by the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (CPP). They provide a way to compile code conditionally. You can enable the use of the CPP by adding the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` on top of a file.

Many programs that deal with Haskell code set some macros for the preprocessor (eg. GHC sets `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__` to the version of GHC), so one can conditionally compile code, for instance to use different properitary libraries for Hugs and GHC.

Answer (score 3):

If you run your Haskell compiler with the `-cpp` option, it will first preprocess the source files with the CPP (C Pre Processor).

Take a look at the section 4.11.3. Options affecting the C pre-processor [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/options-phases.html).