# Haskell list drives in Windows

Tags: windows, haskell

How can I list disk drives in Haskell? I would like to get disk drive letters on Windows and get just "/" on Linux. Is it possible? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: It seems that you want [`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364975%28VS.85%29.aspx), but it is not wrapped in [`System.Win32.File`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Win32/2.2.2.0/doc/html/System-Win32-File.html).

Comment: Is there any way to do it without Win32? I ask because I can compile it only on windows and I will lose portability...

Comment: Not that I know of, and I doubt it. You can use `CPP` pragmas though.

Comment: What do you mean by CPP pragmas?

Comment: He means #ifdef conditional compilation directives from C PreProcessor.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6362016/946226 for some discussion of them.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: That is interesting. Do you have any example?

Comment: See [https://github.com/jystic/unix-compat/blob/master/src/System/PosixCompat.hs] which uses the predefined flag `mingw32_HOST_OS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import System.Process
c = do
  res <- readProcess "wmic" ["logicaldisk","get","caption"] ""
  --print res
  -- clean up the output
  print $ init $ map (take 2) $ drop 1(lines res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try just enumerating all 26 possible drive letters and seeing if they exist using `doesDirectoryExist` from `System.Directory`. I *believe* that would work...